# Workflow field update on date field to add 10 years

Tags: workflow, date, field-update

I am not too good with formulas but i have a workflow and i need to create a formula on my field update that will update my custom field "End Date" 10 years ahead in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need workflow here, as it can be implemented by means of formula field. Formula for your "End Date" field is:

```
DATE( 
YEAR(DateField) + 10, 
MONTH(DateField), 
DAY(DateField)
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addYears() method of DataTime.

DateTime newDate = System.Now().addYears(1);

DateTime Methods documentation:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

Hope this helps :)

Comment: There is no add years in a wfr formula, only apex